# Prevent postback on server-side property change

Tags: asp.net, postback, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a simple CalendarExtender (from AjaxControlToolkit) attached to a textbox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="StartDateText" runat="server" MaxLength="10" Width="70px" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="StartDateText_TextChanged" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageCalendarStartDate" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Calendar_scheduleHS.png" AlternateText="Click to show calendar" />
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="StartDateCalendarExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="StartDateText" PopupButtonID="ImageCalendarStartDate" />
```

In order to control user input, I have the `AutoPostBack` set to `True` on the textbox, as well as a function on the `TextChanged` event (although `TextChanged` isn't the issue here).

In `Page_Load`, I have:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        StartDateCalendarExtender.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    }
}
```

On opening the page, `Page_Load` sets the date, but the AutoPostBack triggers a postback right after `Page_Load`, calling it again with `IsPostBack` set to true.

**Is there a server-side way to prevent this postback?**

I tried setting the `AutoPostBack` property to false, changing the `SelectedDate`, and setting it back to true, but it keeps firing a postback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that because you give the date on the extender, then the extender add it to the text box, then the text box trigger the post back.

How about try to set the text at the TextBox at the first place.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // remove that
        // StartDateCalendarExtender.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
        // and direct set it to the text box.
        StartDateText.Text = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Maybe you need to format the DateTime the way you want it.

Comment: Very astute, sir. However, my CalendarExtender then no longer has the date, and when I open it, some other date is selected (CalendarExtender actually defaults to `DateTime.Now`. Suppose I want to set it to `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)`.

Comment: @MPelletier To me is working, the control is read and show the date time from the text box...

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I did something else incorrectly. Thanks!

Comment: Drats, that leaves `CalendarExtender.SelectedDate` empty, unset.

Comment: Ah! `SelectedDate` is a bit of a misnommer. You gotta use the textbox only.